# C++ general definition questions (ADT, members, constructors, and overloading)

Tags: c++

Good afternoon!

Here I have a review sheet of stuff that I believe have been only gone over maybe once in class, without any followup until now that we have the final review. I was hoping someone could assist me with some general multiple choice problems. I'm going to answer them to the best of my abilities, but since my knowledge far from perfect, please point out if I'm misunderstanding some of it.

Here are the questions:

```
The private members of an ADT are directly accessible
   a) in non-member functions
   b) in member functions
   c) in friend functions
   d) both b and c        <<<
```

Here I chose answer (d) because as far as I know, an ADT (abstract data type) refer to classes and structs? If that's the case, then only (a) is incorrect.

```
The purpose of a constructor is to
   a) use the other member functions to initialize the object
   b) make sure a new object is properly initialized        <<<
   c) use the data members to call the member functions
   d) none of the above
```

The answer is supposed to be (b) but I thought the object is initialized through member variables (which are the private variables) rather than the constructor which is a member function?

```
An ADT typically
   a) keeps its data members private
   b) has public member functions to provide access to its private data
   c) provides private member functions to make its data public
   d) both a and b        <<<
```

No clue here. What's the difference between (b) and (c)? Based on the clarity of the wording alone though, I'd have to go with (d).

```
In C++ you can overload
   a) member functions
   b) non-member functions
   c) operators
   d) all of the above        <<<
```

I really only chose (d) based on google searches since it turns up overloading for all of the first three choices. I don't think I've ever even seen operators being overloaded yet though, so I'm simply not too confident about this one.

Again, apologies for asking such basic questions, but I just feel hard pressed to find straight up answers and anything plain English or definition related seems like they've been just glazed over in class.

Comment: For `The purpose of a constructor is to`, yes the inner members may set _themselves_ up but the owning object may still need to _connect or wire_ them together somehow.  (At least, that's how I like to think of it)

Answer (score 0):

> the constructor which is a member function

The constructor in a class is a special function that is only called once when the object is initialized.  This is different from regular member functions that can be called anytime after the object is constructed.  So, it is not your average member function

> What's the difference between (b) and (c)?

(c) is wrong.  How will private functions, that can only be accessed by the stuff from question 1, expose data publicly?

Other than those two points I noticed, you seem to have the right ideas.

Operators are overloaded every time you define an operator :)  Just think of the operator symbol as the "function name" and you should see that that "function name" has all kinds of different types it can accept.